# Linking code coverage to version control

Tags: php, git, testing, version-control, code-coverage

Before I commit a change, I'd like to be sure that all of it has been tested, either automatically or manually with a code coverage report, but there is lots of legacy code that doesn't have automated tests, and won't be affected by my changes.

Is there a tool that can cross reference a diff from a version control tool with a code coverage report and make sure everything that has been changed has been run?

I realise that with code coverage, this may give a false sense of security, and with something like this, even more so, but I think it would be worth trying. I use git and PHP - I've used XCache's code coverager interface to browse what I have run, and it's useful, but it would be great if something could run automatically at git commit or push time.

Comment: Voting to migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *git* diffs, there is a tool named [diff-cover](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff-cover), which can check coverage. It takes Cobertura XML coverage reports and compares with the output of `git diff`. It then reports coverage information for lines in the diff.

Given the proper coverage xml file, you can use this command to check the coverage of your changes compared to the `master` branch:

```
$ diff-cover coverage.xml
```

It is also pretty simple to integrate with a CI server, as long as it can provide you with the commit you need to compare with, like `$GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT` in Jenkins.

Comment: how do you get Cobertura XML format when running PHP unit tests? when using this tool with `--coverage-clover=coverage.xml` it errors out with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) build server (there are lots of [excellent, free build servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Software)). One of the build steps would be running code coverage. You could set it up to ignore legacy code and calculate coverage only for non-legacy code. Then you set it up to fail the build if coverage < xx%. Or even fail if coverage % decreases from the previous build.

Comment: Good idea; doing heavy work like code coverage at every checkin or push makes version control much more painful to use, so people will hate it.  Instead, don't let people push into the mainline at all; test people's branches in a continuous integration server (I like gitbuilder) and then merge those branches into the mainline only after the continuous integration approves them.

Comment: Re-reading my question, I emphasized it wrong. The point is not that it runs at commit time and prevents me committing. The point is that I can be sure I have run though all the code I have changed before I commit it. Being able to be auto-run at commit / push time was only a minor bonus, not the real requirement.

Comment: @rjmunro: I know my answer isn't exactly what you're asking for, but I think it's as close as you can get.