# How do I map code coverage reports to a diff file?

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

I have code coverage running from PhpUnit, and I can generate a diff file in Git that will show me what's about to be released.

How would I go about mapping one to the other, so that I can say the code we are about to release is covered by our tests?

Ideally, this would be something that could be run automatically as a build step in Jenkins.

Comment: While not identical, this question is similar enough that the answers should be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29703283/22146

Answer (score -1):

Before you run your phpunit tests by your Ant / maven build, run a phpscript. In this php script copy every file specified in the git file which is about to be release along with the matching unit tests to a temporary directory. Of course this requires that you use [proper naming conventions and structure for unit tests](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/45/PHPUnit%20Best%20Practices%20Presentation.pdf). Run phpunit on the temporary directory

```
-application
  -app
  -tests
-temp
  -app
  -tests
```

when you run your phpunit in your build file include a clover report

```
phpunit --coverage-clover="clover.xml" temp/tests
```

In Jenkins you can mark the build as unstable if the clover.xml doesn't meet a specified % coverage.

[image: clover target in jenkins]

This should work. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: This won't work, because a file from diff can depend on a file *not* from diff (not changes/created), and thus copied files will not be linkable.